# Proofs of elementary number theory question such that $q\nmid(n^p-p)$ for all $n$ for given prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p$ is a prime, prove that there exists a prime $q$ such that
> $q\nmid (n^p-p)$ for any natural number $n$.

I want to know of the other proofs, espicially for those not employing the notion of order. In my opinion this question is pretty beautiful as for my first glance it is difficult. For instance, $p=3$ my first thought is to find a prime $q$ such that $n^3-3\equiv r\pmod{q}$ for some $r$ that is not solvable. Here are what I tried.

**Lemma** If $p$ is a prime, we can find a prime $q$ dividing $(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +p+1)$, such that $p^2\nmid(q-1)$.

*Proof.* Observe that, the product of primes of the form $kp^2+1$, will end up being of the form $k'p^2+1$ as we can see here $(k_1p^2+1)(k_2p^2+1)=k_1k_2p^4+k_1p^2+k_2p^2+1=kp^2+1$. Thus, inductively we have the claim.

Therefore, we can find $q|(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +p+1):=L$, where $q$ is not of the form $kp^2+1$. Otherwise, all prime factors of $L$ will be of that form and so
$$p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +p+1=p^2k+1,$$
which is impossible as we will have $p^2|p$  $\blacksquare$

For $p=2$ we can let $q=3$ so that $n^2-2\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$. Now we assume $p>2$ so $p$ is odd and we will prove by contradiction that for some chosen $q$, $n$ will be satisfying that $n^p\not\equiv p\pmod q$.

Let a prime $q>p$ (so $q$ is odd prime) such that $q|(p^p-1)$, which is always possible because we can choose $q|(p^p-1)$ but $q\nmid(p-1)$ then $p$ is $\text{ord}_{q}(p)$. We can choose $q$ satisfying this property because $\gcd(p-1,p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +1)=1$, for if there is a prime $r|(p-1)$ and $r|(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +1)$ then $0\equiv p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots +1\equiv 1+1+\cdots 1\equiv p\pmod r$ so $r|(p-1)$ and $r|p\Longrightarrow r|1$. We mean $\text{ord}_{q}(p)$ to be the smallest number such that $p^{\text{ord}_{q}(p)}\equiv 1 \pmod q$. In our argument since $q\nmid (p-1)$, $\text{ord}_{q}(p)>1$ and it is the factor of $p$ so it must be $p$.

Since $\text{ord}_{q}(p)=p$ we have $p|\varphi(q)=(q-1)$, hence $p\le (q-1)/2$ or $p<q$. Also as $p|(q-1)$ we have $q=kp+1$. The numbers of the form $n^p-p$ is not divisible by $q$ for any $n$. If there exists such $n$ (of course $q\nmid n$ otherwise $q|n$ then $n^p-p\equiv -p\pmod{q}$ and $q\nmid p$), $n^p\equiv p\pmod q$, then $1\equiv n^{q-1}\equiv n^{pk}\equiv p^k \pmod q$. Thus, we must have $\text{ord}_q(p)=p|k\Longrightarrow p^2|(q-1)$, which is false if we select $q$ as in lemma above $\blacksquare$

Cited: [link](https://pantip.com/topic/33003085/comment3) It's in Thai, but the problem can be translated as I quoted. I want to knpw other solutions because there is someone suggests (also in Thai) to use contradiction and if the number is divisible then it is composite, and thus can be written as a product of primes. I don't know how to use just these concepts to show this problem.

I don't know where the real source is but this is where I found the problem.

Comment: Please cite the source of the problem

Comment: @BillDubuque I added the source I knew.

Comment: What is your justification for the claim $\,k\mid {\rm ord}_q(p)?\ \ $

Comment: Ok, you fixed that. But now where is the "lemma above" which disproves $p^2\mid q-1?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I hope this time my proof is valid. Actually, I think the lemma should extend to all other than $2$ that is not of the form $kp^2+1$.